# type I phase detector - analog vs digital inputs

Tags: phase-detector

Section 13.13.2.A of the Art of Electronics (3e) describes a type-I phase detector. It is explained that the analog version of this circuit uses a multiplier and the digital version uses an xor gate. Additionally, this quote seems to indicate that the xor gate is a digital "version" of an analog multiplier:

> The type I phase detector is applicable to either
>   analog- or digital-input signals, and performs a simple multiplication of the inputs. For digital signals this is just an exclusive-OR gate...

I fail to see how an xor gate gives the same result as an analog multiplier with digital inputs. Here's the digital circuit and corresponding voltage output as a function of phase.
[image]

How this circuit works and why it functions as a phase detector make sense to me. However, I don't see what the analogous analog circuit would be. For instance, replacing the xor gate with a mixer produces the following circuit:

[image]

If I assume that the RC lowpass filter produces a perfect average of the mixer output over a period (and for simplicity both input signals have identical frequency), then the relation between \$V_{out}\$ and \$\phi\$ is shown in the following plot.

[image]

I guess I could invert the output (e.g. amplifier with gain=-1) to get a roughly analogous result. Is this what is done? If not, how can I implement an analog type-I phase detector (presumably with a mixer)? Did I misinterpret the phrasing used, and what was really meant was that a mixer is used as part of the phase detector but is not actually analogous to the xor gate?

Something else I've missed?

Comment: What did you expect?  Two square waves almost the same frequency and 50% duty cycle to come out with f1-f2 or DC 0,1 ?  And F1+f2 so LPF cuts the noise.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 not sure I follow... Everything I got I believe makes sense. But then I don't see how an xor gate is analogous to a mixer.

Comment: Do understand truth table? 1+1=0, 0+0=0?

Comment: I see how that describes the xor, but shouldn't a multiplier be 1*1=1,0*0=0,etc.?

Comment: The XOR gate adds in binary but like the diode full bridge if you had AC inputs and both are 1 or 0 then the output is 0 current and only Outputs DC current when one side is 1 and other input = 0. The. Result out is DC and 2f  because the multiplying of 2 time domain inputs results in the sum and difference frequencies.

Comment: press Reset to see it Lock On  http://tinyurl.com/udr2ymf

Comment: Did U understand the diode power bridge multiplies +/-1 on AC halfwaves to get full wave rectification like duty cycle errors of XOR Multiplies 1,0 inputs =1

Comment: I'm not sure I got that point... The simulation was very helpful, however.

Comment: Mutliply is time domain XOR Add is in binary state machine but in time domain it adds and subtracts with duty cycle difference in time domain like analog multiplier,  this is a math transform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About logic XOR gates acting as a multiplier....
It is easy to confuse logic states of an XOR. One makes the mistake of assigning logic **low** (a zero) to a multiplier's equivalent of zero volts. That's wrong.
A logic **low** is assigned to some negative voltage, while a logic **high** is assigned to some positive voltage when considering it as a multiplier. Now the logic equivalent to *multiplication* is apparent:

- +1 x +1 = +1
- +1 x -1 = -1
- -1 x +1 = -1
- -1 x -1 = +1

It is striking to look at the transistor arrangement inside an XOR gate of non-saturating **emitter-coupled-logic** chips. The arrangement bears a striking resemblance to a **Gilbert-cell-mixer**, which is often used as a four-quadrant analog multiplier. Shown below is the internals of ECL type MC1674 from Motorola, a triple XNOR done in MECL III...intended for use in PLL applications :
[image: MECL III MC1674 triple XNOR logic gates]

 There are DC offsets to contend with when using XOR, XNOR logic gates as multipliers, since most logic gates don't provide symmetrical input/output voltages about zero volts. 
For this logic chip, Vcc on pin 1 is often considered *ground* while Vee on pin 8 is -5.2V.

- Logic 1 output on pin 15 (inputs on 7,11) is about -0.885V
- Logic 0 output on pin 15 (inputs on 7,11) is about -1.735V

The mid-point of output on pin 15 (about -1.31V) would correspond to nearly zero volts in an analog multiplier.

Comment: The truth table you provided is an xnor, not an xor, right? This brings me back to part of the original question which is that xnor"="multiplier and xor"="inverted multiplier, not xor"="multiplier. Did I just interpret the comparison between xor and multiplier too literally?

Comment: This chip is classed as **XNOR** for positive logic, and **XOR** for negative logic. Does it matter to you which slope your PLL locks onto? One slope shuns lock, while the other attracts lock. You should be concerned that locking occurs about mid-way between most +ve voltage and most -ve voltage, and not too close to those peak or valley voltages.

Comment: I misunderstood how the locking mechanism works for type I. I get your point now.

Answer (score 0):

In binary math, multiplication is done by shift and add while while the XOR gate logic adds.  The output is the DC phase error and 2f pulse (difference phase/frequency, f and sum).

[Learn with simulation here.](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%200%200.000005%207.010541234668786%2065%205%2050%0A158%20432%20224%20464%20224%200%0Ac%20528%20224%20528%20256%200%200.000001%20-4.152229865988157%0Ar%20528%20288%20592%20288%200%205000%0Ar%20528%20320%20592%20320%200%2081500%0Aw%20592%20288%20592%20320%200%0Ag%20592%20320%20592%20352%200%0A154%20144%20192%20256%20192%200%202%205%205%0AR%20144%20176%2080%20176%200%202%2060%202.5%202.5%200%200.5%0Aw%20144%20208%20144%20320%200%0Aw%20144%20320%20432%20320%200%0Aw%20432%20192%20432%20224%200%0AO%20144%20320%2096%20320%200%0Ag%20336%20240%20336%20256%200%0Aw%20256%20192%20256%20160%200%0A403%20160%2096%20288%20160%200%2013_64_0_4354_5_0.1_0_2_13_3%0Ac%20336%20192%20336%20240%200%200.000009999999999999999%202.268721438360399%0Ar%20256%20192%20336%20192%200%201000%0Aw%20336%20192%20432%20192%202%0A403%200%20240%20128%20304%200%209_64_0_4354_5_0.1_0_2_9_3%0A403%200%2096%20128%20160%200%207_64_0_4354_5_0.1_0_2_7_3%0A403%20368%2096%20496%20160%200%2017_64_0_20738_5_0.1_0_2_17_3%0Ap%20432%20192%20512%20192%201%204%0Ax%20713%20-6%20903%20-3%204%2024%20press%5CsReset%5Cs%5Cq%3E%3E%3E%0Ao%207%2016%200%2036874%205%200.00009765625%200%202%207%203%0Ao%2011%2016%200%2036878%205%200.00009765625%200%201%0Ao%2013%2016%200%2037122%205%200.1%200%202%2013%203%0Ao%2015%2016%200%204354%205%200.1%200%202%2015%203%0A)

Think of the square wave clock as a multiplier +/-1 of the input signal. 1=Invert, 0 = Normal  then the output is the sum and difference frequencies. If both at same f then output Vdc= phase difference.